# Rails AJAX click method needs to be clicked twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In rails 4, I'm trying to use jquery to hide a certain element on a page when the submit button is clicked. However, the element "span" is not hidden until I click the button a second time. This is my create.js.erb:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#actor").hide();
  });
});
```

This is my _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@actor, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <% if @actor.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <p>Please correct the following <%= pluralize(@actor.errors.count, "error") %>:</p>
            <ul>
                <% @actor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :Name %>
        <%= f.text_field :fname %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :Surname %>
        <%= f.text_field :lname %>
    </div>    
    <div>
        <%= f.submit @actor.new_record? ? "Create actor" : "Update actor", :id => 'button' %>
    </div>
    <span id="actor">
        Test text...hide me please...
    </span>
<% end %>
```

I would like it to hide the element on the first click. Any advice?

Comment: Please post the code that includes the element you're trying to hide and the button.

Comment: @RhapX, I have updated the post with the code from the form.

Comment: @DarkNawg It's been a long time since I took a look at rails code, but it looks like your `id="button"` is only being set when the button is an `update` action. I could be wrong. Please confirm.

Comment: @RhapX, Yes, it does look that way, but it doesn't matter which side the id is on. The result is the same. Where else can I put it?

Comment: @DarkNawg What I was getting at is if `id="button"` is only being set on the `'update` button, then that's the only case where the jQuery action will be called. Therefore, if the default action is 'Create actor', the action would not be called. After you've created an actor (action 1), the button then shows `update` (action 2) and would be why your button works on the second click. Maybe i'm a bit off but it's the only way that makes sense to me because your code works just fine on a single button action.

Comment: @RhapX, yes I get you. I tried it without the actions. Just <%= f.submit :id => %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the click method solved the problem.

Comment: yay! There's a lot of unspoken things to keep in mind when learning rails for the new time. It's easy to forget that these are executed automatically, thus adding an event handler like click is superfluous and problematic.